# How do I sort this hashmap?

Tags: java, android

```
for(int i=0;i<videos.length();i++){                     
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
    JSONObject e = videos.getJSONObject(i);

    map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
    map.put("title",  e.getString("title"));
    map.put("description",  e.getString("description"));
    mylist.add(map);
}
```

Hi, I am trying to sort the code above alphabetically. I know tree maps, are supposed to be used for this sorta thing, but it would be a bigger hassle to to do that. I am having errors arranging the hash map, and have looked at numerous examples.

Comment: You may use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap if you know the order. Here I think you can use it. Otherwise you can use TreeMap, this should work.

Comment: Why aren't you using TreeMap when it's specifically designed for this case?  What sort of hassle are you running into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a big hassle to use a TreeMap.

```
    for(int i=0;i<videos.length();i++){                     
        Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();    
        JSONObject e = videos.getJSONObject(i);

        map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
        map.put("title",  e.getString("title"));
        map.put("description",  e.getString("description"));
        mylist.add(map);
    }
```

Even if that's a lot of hassle (e.g. if you made the mistake of declaring `mylist` to be a `List<HashMap>`), you've got little choice.  A `HashMap` is inherently unsorted / unordered and you can't change that fact.  If you could use a `LinkedHashMap` instead, you could add the entries in alphabetical order, but if you can change the map type you may as well use a `TreeMap`.

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be `AbstractMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();` ?

Comment: @Vladimir - oops ... corrected.  But it should be `Map` not `AbstractMap`

Comment: @Vladimir- You could do that, but just saying Map is fine.  The AbstractMap is mostly to be inherited from and doesn't offer anything interfacewise over Map (IIRC)

Comment: @StephenC Indeed, my mistake.

Comment: I just ended up changing everything to a treemap. It was a lot of work, but I guess its better.

Comment: @templatetypedef - the problem with using AbstractMap is that not all Map types have AbstractMap as a super-class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort a HashMap.

"The Map interface provides three collection views, which allow a map's contents to be viewed as a set of keys, collection of values, or set of key-value mappings. The order of a map is defined as the order in which the iterators on the map's collection views return their elements. Some map implementations, like the TreeMap class, make specific guarantees as to their order; others, like the HashMap class, do not."

Cited form: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to sort the list, you need to implement a comparator. You can do something like this:

```
public class VideoComparator implements Comparator<Map<String, String>> {
    private final String key;

    public VideoComparator(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        return this == object;
    }

    public int compare(Map<String, String> map1, Map<String, String> map2) {
        return map1.get(key).compareTo(map2.get(key));
    }
}
```

Then you can sort your maps by title like this:

```
Collections.sort(mylist, new VideoComparator("title"));
```